# What is the maximum number of characters that can be stored in a string variable In C#?

Tags: c#, string, variables, max

i was wondering what is the maximum number of characters that can be stored in a string variable In C#

Comment: @HansPassant on 32bit applications I assume? or does 2 GB also apply to 64Bit applications?

Comment: It's worth noting that you don't "store characters in a string".  A string consists of characters that are there from the point the object is initialized.  Strings are immutable and shouldn't be thought of as a storage medium.  Your question is better phrased as "what is the maximum length of a string?"

Answer (score 2):

> The maximum size of a String object in memory is 2-GB, or about 1 billion characters.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0